# Is it possible to style up an <input type="submit"> in a form with no classes or ids?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to style up a form within the Wishlist Member plugin in Wordpress and there isn't a template where I can physically go into and add classes, id's, etc. So I was wondering if there was a way to style up an `<input type="submit">` with no class or id without affecting the `<input type="text">` fields using javascript maybe. Thanks.

Comment: Wonderful. All worked well. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

You can add style with CSS even if there is no class/id. The following selects all `input` elements with attribute `type="submit"`:

```
input[type="submit"]{
   /* style */
}
```

The above is very generic, it's better to be more exclusiver. So include some of its parents , preferable those with an ID/class:

```
div#someID form input[type="submit"]{
   /* style */
}
```

(assuming a parent `<div id="someID">`)

Comment: In addition, the form will probably have a name or id, so you can add form#id or form[name="name"] in front of that declaration if you want to limit your changes to that particular form.

Comment: I've never heard of Wishlist Member plugin, nor have I seen an example of it. So I cannot confirm whether the form has an ID or not.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
input[type=submit] {
    yourCss
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I only have 13 points, so I am unable to leave comments, which is where this belongs. But, it is important to note that:

```
input[type="submit"]{
/* style */
}
```

needs to have it's `background:somestyle;` stylized in order for it to work (except IE6, of course).